# Showing that a subset of the plane is locally path-connected

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

> Show that $A:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \in \Bbb Q \iff y \in \Bbb Q\} \subset \Bbb R^2$ is locally path-connected.

I've been trying to think about this problem for a while now and I don't even understand the set $\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x \in \Bbb Q \iff y \in \Bbb Q\}$. The closes I can think of this is just $\Bbb Q^2$, but I don't understand this pathological condition $x \in \Bbb Q \iff y \in \Bbb Q$.

To show it's locally path-connected I think I have to show that for every $x \in A$ there is a neighborhood basis containing only locally path-connected sets?

This definition of locally path-connectedness seems a bit overwhelming. It's like three different conditions. Is there some characterization of this that could be useful here?

Comment: $A=\mathbb{Q}^2\cup\mathbb{I}^2$ where $\mathbb{I}$ are the irrationals. Locally path connected means that for any $(x,y)\in A$ there exists some $\epsilon >0$ such that  $B_A((x,y),\epsilon)$ is path connected.

Comment: This is not $\Bbb Q ^2$, but rather the union  $\Bbb Q ^2 \cup \Bbb I^2$, where by $\Bbb I$ I mean the set of irrational numbers $\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$. This is what the condition is implying, that the second coordinate is rational (resp. irrational) if and only if the first one is also rational (resp. irrational). So there are no points like $(1, e)$ or $(\pi, 2)$ in $A$, for instance.

Comment: @jcneek locally path connected is not exactly what you wrote. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#locally_path-connected

Answer (score 1):

$A=\mathbb{Q}^2\cup\mathbb{I}^2$ is locally path-connected, i.e. any
$(a,b)\in A$ admits a basis $(V_i)_{i
\in I}$ of neighbourhoods in $A$ such that each $V_i$ is path-connected: take $V_r=U_r\cap A$ for any positive $r$, $U_r$ being the square $\{(x,y)\in {\mathbb R}^2:
|x-a|+|y-b|<r\}.$
Any two points of $V_r$ are joined inside $V_r$ by a line segment of slope $1$ or $-1$, or by a union of two such segments.

Comment: What is the motivation for this square $U_r$ you defined?

Comment: It is the most natural neighbourhood of $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ satisfying the property I indicated, which makes $V_r$ path-connected. The idea is that if $(x,y)\in A$ then   $\forall t\in\mathbb R\quad(x+t,y\pm t)\in A.$